# Long URLs (Bitly and TinyURL)

Tags: long-integer, url, tinyurl

I'm sitting with a problem where I need to pass more than 2000 characters from my Flash application to an HTML page which reads the information and displays the correct options made in the Flash app the person came from.

All's good but on the final stage, when the user needs to post their choices to a form, the character cannot be sent because the string is too long.

Is there a way to use a service such as Bitly or TinyURL to send these long string and for them to be "deconstruction" on the other end when the form is sent?

Otherwise, is there another solution to this problem?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Internet Explorer? Because the problem might even be that the [maximum URL size](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html) is 2083. Otherwise it could also be that the input field is too short (see the [maxlength attribute of the input element](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_maxlength.asp))

Comment: Yes this was the problem in the end. What I had to do was put my long strings in a hidden div and then extract it using jQuery which then put it in the hidden input field. The form supports more text than the query string so that worked out well.

Thanks Marc!

Answer (score 5):

You should be using POST to pass variables, instead of GET. That way you don't need to worry about sending URL parameters.  This is an option in Flash.

Comment: Thanks Khan, I will try that instead!